# Idiom for putting an end to something that has been dragging out way too long?

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

Is there an idiom in English that means to put an end to something that has been dragging out way too long?

Comment: The close reason does seem wrong, and @YosefBaskin's comment was what first came to mind **and should have been an answer,** but there needs to be a bit more detail in the question. We have [detailed guidance for request questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/phrase-requests/info) which will help here. Naama, please read the help page and [edit] your question.

Comment: OK, so I don't know why this was re-opened when it needs more information. @Naama, please read the help and supply more information.

Answer (score 1):

One can **put the final nail in the coffin**.

> *Putting the [last/final] nail in the coffin* means that something was done that will finally destroy or ruin something else. For example,
> "When the girl scored a 58 on her exam, it put the nail in the coffin
> for her already failing class grade". [[Ry; HiNative](https://hinative.com/questions/18983173)]

Inclusion of *last / final* indicates that there is a long history of decline.

The event bringing about the end may be a deliberate act, or unintended (whether deserved or not).

.........

> - *The last nail in the coffin is going to be that report, [I] can tell you as a lawyer* .... – [Comey Giuliani;
>   Definitions.net](https://www.definitions.net/sample-sentences/coffin)

.........

> - *Moise's assassination is the final nail in the coffin for them*, .... – [Vania Andre;
>   Definitions.net](https://www.definitions.net/sample-sentences/coffin)]

.........

> - *I really do hope that will put the final nail in the coffin.* – [Jo Swabe;
>   Cefinitions.net](https://www.definitions.net/sample-sentences/coffin)